# Update List of objects based on matching type in Dictionary and another List using C# collection

Tags: c#, list, linq, dictionary, collections

I have a list of objects of below-defined CustomType. i.e. `List<CustomType>`

```
public class CustomType
{
     public int Id {get;set;}
     public string Value {get;set;}
     public bool IsCorrect {get; set;}
}
```

Now I have a `Dictionary<int, String>` which contains some keys which match to **Id** field of **CustomType**.
I have another `List<string>` which contains the values same as in the **Values** in the **dictionary**.
Now I want to update the **IsCorrect = true** for entries in the `List<CustomType>`for which `List<string>` values match to the dictionary **values** and corresponding **keys** in dictionary matches to the **Id** of **CustomType**.

I have tried the following,
At the first place, I tried to get the intersect of List and dictionary like below

```
var commonKeys = list
    .Where(k => dictionaty.ContainsValue(k))
    .Select(k => dictionary)
    .Select(m => m.Keys);
```

Now common keys will contain the common keys based on matching values in the dictionary, Now I need to update **List** based on matching **keys** in **commonKeys** with the matching **Id** of **CustomType**.

Comment: Is this executed to the database or in memory? also please show what you have tried

Comment: This operation needs to be performed in memory. I will update the question, what I have tried

Comment: Not sure I understood the purpose of the other `List<string>`.

Comment: Hi Gilad, as per my business requirement I have 3 different collections, 1. List of objects 2. Dictionary and 3. List<string> and data is getting populated in this, Now I have to process data by joining all 3 collection. This case can be considerd as if we have 3 different tables in datbase then by joining we can simply get the desired result. But here I have to perform operation in memory

Comment: That is fine but so you want the custom types that their id is in the dictionary keys and their (the custom types) value is in the `List<string>`?

Comment: `.Select(k => dictionary)` just selects the entire dictionary, no matter what the preceeding where clause selected. Sincerely, I have no idea, what you are trying to achieve. Please provide real code and describe a real problem instead of talking about nonconcrete types and values.

Comment: @Gliad, I am looking the join like this -> Id in CustomType = Key in Dictionary and Value in Dictionary = Value in List<string>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it like this: Retrieve the desired items and then iterate them to set the `IsCorrect`:

```
Dictionary<int,string> ids;
List<string> values
List<CustomType> customTypes;

foreach(var customType in customTypes.Where(item => ids.ContainsKey(item.Id) && 
                                                    values.Contains(ids[item.Id])))
{
    customType.IsCorrect = true;
}
```

Comment: @AshishShukla - thanks for accepting my answer :) glad it helped. It do recommend though that you create a `HashSet` for the `List<string>` as the search will be in `O(1)` instead of the current `O(1)`. But the time I wanted to make the update Fabio posted his and I didn't want to override it :)

Answer (score 1):

Optimized approach of  Gilad's answer - with `HashSet<string>`. With `HashSet.Contains` method, search will be as fast as key for `Dictionary` - O(1)

```
var stringSet = new HashSet<string>(stringValues);
var filtered = customTypes.Where(item => dictionary.ContainsKey(item.Id))
                          .Where(item => stringSet.Contains(dictionary[item.Id]));

foreach (var item in filtered)
{
    item.IsCorrect = true;
}
```